# How do I compile and run a project on github?

Tags: github

I don't really know anything about github, I don't know how do I run a project on it. I'm specifically talking about this proj.:

https://github.com/User344/GodnestCSGOTool

Comment: You don't. Github hosts your project source files using git, and provides wiki, issues, etc. But it's not a build tol, nor a deployment platform.

Comment: You actually can build there with travis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the project to your computer, click Clone or download, then Download Zip (see picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYJXd.png). Unzip it and you can run the project on your computer. Read the README.md for Dependency.

You can clone the project, which is also a way to download it, but you can also contribute to the project.... Follow this tutorial: 
https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

I think you should read about GitHub and version control first, Udacity has a tutorial that I found extremely helpful. Just google "How to Use Git and GitHub"